# Is there another way to calculate days aged?

Tags: ms-access, expression

I am trying to calculate days aged on Access table, but since Access does not calculate due that Close date is blank, date will only be input once action is closed, it is not a promise date.

So I went and try using following formula on my table(mdr)

Design view > MDR > General > Default value>

Fx = IIf([STATUS]="OPEN", Day()-[OPEN DATE], [CLOSE DATE]-[OPEN DATE])

But i cannot use it, can someone guide to another solution?[image][image]

Comment: Please add a A. sample of existing data B. What you are currently getting C. What you want the result to be

Comment: Please do not SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to SHOUT AT people you're asking to donate their time to help you. Also, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with DefaultValue property. You are trying to build expression for Calculated field in table which is not using Day() function correctly, should be Date() and don't repeat [OPEN DATE] field.

`IIf([STATUS]="OPEN", Date(), [CLOSE DATE])-[OPEN DATE]`

Alternate calculation:

`IIf(IsNull([Close Date]), Date(), [Close Date]) - [Open Date]`

Calculation in query or textbox:

`Nz([Close Date], Date()) - [Open Date]`

Advise not to use UPPER CASE nor spaces in naming convention, better would be **CloseDate**.